# ItemsControl のアイテムにコンボボックスを配置した際、VMからの変更通知がうまく働かない

Tags: c#, wpf, reactivex

ItemsControl にコンボボックスを配置した後、コンボボックスの ItemsSource と SelectedItem をほぼ同時に変化させると正常に反映されないという問題にあたっています。

再現コードは以下の通りです。
最初はコンボボックスの内容はhogeのみで、それが選択されており、5秒後にfugaに変化してそれが自動的に選択されることを意図しています。
しかし、実際には5秒後にコンボボックスの項目はfugaに変化しますが、無選択状態になります。
さらに5秒後にfugaが選択されることから、十分に時間をおけばVMからも選択できるということがわかります。

原因、回避方法はありますか。
再現コードでは INotifyPropertyChanged を自力で実装していますが、実際は ReactiveProperty を使用しています。
それぞれのコンボボックスの項目は別のものである必要があります。

// xaml

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowContext/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DdlList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window
```

// データコンテキスト

```
public class MainWindowContext
{
    public List<DdlCtx> DdlList { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowContext()
    {
        DdlList = new List<DdlCtx>()
        {
            new DdlCtx()
        };

        _ = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            DdlList.First().Update();
        });

        _ = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            DdlList.First().Select();
        });
    }
}

public class DdlCtx : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> Items { get; private set; }
    public string Selected { get; set; }

    public DdlCtx()
    {
        Items = new List<string>() { "hoge" };
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));

        Selected = Items.First();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Items = new List<string>() { "fuga" };
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));

        Selected = Items.First();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
    }

    public void Select()
    {
        Selected = Items.First();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: 解決、お疲れ様でした。スタック・オーバーフローでは、他の回答をもとに自己解決した場合、それを別の回答として投稿できます（推奨されています）。質問と回答を分けて、可読性を上げるためです。もしよろしければ、ご回答として再投稿して頂ければ幸いです。より詳しくは、ヘルプセンターの記事をご覧ください: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: 新しいコメントとして投稿したらマイナス評価となっているのですが、元のままの方がよかったのでしょうか。

Comment: 回答のほうが良いです。ご投稿下さりありがとうございました！　少なくとも質問の中に回答があるよりは良くなったと思います。マイナス票を投じられた方が何故そうしたのかはよく分かりませんが（実際、私は良い回答だと思います）、暫くすると閲覧者が増えて是正されていくと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。
実際のコードでは

```
// 初期化
ReactiveProperty<List<string>> Source = ...;
ReadOnlyReactiveProperty<List<string>> Items;
Items = Source.ToReadOnlyReactiveProperty();

// Update (UIスレッド)
await 時間のかかる処理
Source.Value = ...
Selected.Value = ...
```

のようにしていました。
ここで、何らかの理由でプロパティ変更通知がUpdateを抜けた後に発生するために、

Itemsの値変更
→Selectedの値変更
→Itemsの通知
→SelectedがItemsの中から見つからなくなったのでUI側からnullをセット
→Itemsの通知

という順序でnullがセットされたままになった、と考えられます。

ただItemsをReactivePropertyにして直接変更すると即座に通知してくれる様で、その辺の挙動がわかっていない...

解決策としてはItemsとSelectedを初期化する際にImmediateSchedulerを指定し、値変更が必ずUIスレッドから行われるようにしました。

Answer (score 1):

Update()メソッドがTask.Delay()からUIスレッドと異なるスレッドで呼び出されることが原因ではないでしょうか?
端的に書くと、下のようにDispatcherを噛ましてやれば正常に更新されます。
タイマーの入れ方やスレッドの同期に関しては他にもいろいろなアプローチがあると思いますが、分かりやすい例として。

```
public void Update()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Items = new List<string>() { "fuga" };
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));

        Selected = Items.First();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
    }));
}
```

Comment: 再現コードではうまくいきました、が、実際のコードではうまくいかないようです...  参考にしながら同期コンテキスト周りを重点に調べてみます。

Comment: 編集のとおり、同期を重点的に調べたところ解決しました。ありがとうございました。